# Why the "Low Quality" answers reason looks like tyranny of the user?

Tags: discussion

#### If...

I am try to add my decisive solution to the existing answers without of any concurrency to differentiate answer set I mean.

Should to say it feels look alike some tyranny from the community and what I want to say to the Meta it is that THE QUESTION should include different ANSWERS to teach users toward their needs and moderation should not looks like mafia wars.

If people go to the community to solve their real life bugs why they should tolerate these immodest mercenary tricks!?

### Some clarifying

Look, the Meta, my Question looking really BAD and still on hold, but single Answer looking GOOD and obviously useful for community. I do not wound with these negatives and do not try to ask for policy changes alike Askubuntu's bot modifications despite the fact that is really possible and exclusive way to talk about "what is not right here". My exclusive reason to respond for a questions at Askubuntu is only reason to be useful. Thus I talk about collective automatism and an ILLUSION of users be motivated to react to common AUTHORITATIVE PRONOUNCE to decide to hold the Questions, Answers and etc.

Thank you for community negativeness however it do not change my view. Because if a community do not accept Metaphors for what the hell this META?

Comment: It's not clear what you are referring to, can you clarify? Please [edit] your question to do that.

Comment: my view it is a commons

Comment: I do not want to concrete the problem. I feel and I said about.

Comment: Hope it is sufficient for a discussion ?

Comment: I still have no idea what you are really talking about. Are you talking about flagging reasons?

Comment: Approximately yes. About estimating the reason "Low Quality". For example answer correct but too short. However polemics too teddy and mostly stupid.

Comment: good proof )) unfortunately it is not a weather. but sure just some report :D

Comment: Okay I found this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/569084/40581 It doesn't answer the question and your own the comment leads here. Are you asking for constructive feedback? It doesn't look that way to me and I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: So yes. Maybe some torsion fields. It isn't a joke. And I am not asking for any constructive or usefully reflexive convertibles. Just long time I was silent. Think, that is my tradition by which I should to say what I think about askubuntu.
Thank you.

Comment: And also yes! All questions at Meta should be sterile clear because if you want to speak your philosophy you should go for relevant blog etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're talking in riddle and metaphor. What are these "mercenary tricks"? Where is the tyranny? Mafia wars?

The various low-quality flags and mechanisms aren't a tyrannical Mafia conspiracy, they're there to make sure that people keep their quality up. There's little value in low quality posts because they often don't answer the question or just don't make sense.

There are *automated* flags around low quality too. If you post something really short, the Community bot will flag it for other people *to review*. It doesn't take futher action without somebody else agreeing with it.

Comment: Yes metaphor, but not a riddle. Just in common sense.

Comment: Yes, bot flagging, I am sorry. Then people reviews the post and found the same "Low Quality" alike bots.

Comment: No life inside vinyl I mean ))

Comment: Obviously the Question morose BAD, however the Answer so GOOD. Where the Truth, Meta!?

Comment: @swift vinyl records are nice. wait what are we talking talking about?

Comment: @Mateo_, not the records certainly however about the labels hysteria maybe? :D

Comment: oh my ruined attempt )) negative eight )))) I'm too snobbish …